# How to see the clojure program output in console in Eclipse

Tags: clojure

When running a clojure core.clj as Clojure Application will the following method gets executed and "Test" gets printed?

```
(defn -main
  [& args]
 (println "Test")
```

Answer (score 0):

I know a few of my friends who use `Counterclockwise` plugin on Eclipse.

Here is a [link](https://doc.ccw-ide.org/documentation.html#_what_is_counterclockwise) to their docs. It also has a step by step way to [`Create your first project`](https://doc.ccw-ide.org/documentation.html#first-project)